# How can I make a button scale and rescale on a video

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position, inline

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Luxurious+Script&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Luxurious Script", cursive;
}

body {
  background-color: #e97272;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
}

.nav-brand {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-brand img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-items {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: calc(100% - 900px);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #514d4d;
  color: rgb(236, 200, 0);
}

.items {
  margin: 20px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.Video-Greeting {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.Video-Greeting video {
  width: 100%;
}

.Video-Greeting button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: rgb(236, 200, 0);
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #514d4d;
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" />
  <title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-brand">
      <img src="image\Logo.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <ol class="nav-items">
      <li class="items"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="">Place Order</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ol>
  </nav>

  <div class="Video-Greeting">
    <video autoplay loop muted src="image\Pexels Videos 2706078.mp4"></video>
    <button>Welcome</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to keep my Welcome Button to be stuck on my video and to be able to scale and rescale with video as my browser get smaller or bigger, but it keeps drifting away in one direction when I resize my browser. How can I solve this? I want to make the Welcome Button Be stuck to the middle of the video and for it rescale but at the same time stuck to the video center when making the browser smaller and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `.Video-Greeting`

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

This will make all of it's contents `<button>` and `<video>` center perfectly vertically and horizontally.

Next, the button

```css
z-index:1
```

This allows the `<button>` to be out of the "flow" and not interfere with the `<video>` and vice versa. It's like it's on a layer above everything else on the 3rd dimension.

Also, remove `top` and `left` properties from `<button>` as well.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Luxurious+Script&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 500 3.5vmin/1.2 "Luxurious Script", cursive;
}

body {
  background-color: #e97272;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
}

.nav-brand {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-brand img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-items {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: calc(100% - 900px);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #514d4d;
  color: rgb(236, 200, 0);
}

.items {
  margin: 20px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.greeting {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.greeting video {
  width: 100%;
}

.greeting button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: rgb(236, 200, 0);
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #514d4d;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

footer {
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" />
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-brand">
      <img src="image\Logo.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <ol class="nav-items">
      <li class="items"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="">Place Order</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ol>
  </nav>

  <div class="greeting">
    <video autoplay loop muted src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs34s3.mp4"></video>
    <button>Welcome</button>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine but my button doesn't get smaller with the video is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Forgot about that almost done.

Comment: @JaneSmith OK, it'll scale but you have absolute valued lengths, namely `px` which is ok for small things like borders are margins between close elements. `px` does not scale.